# Swift - Converting JSON date to Swift compatible date

Tags: javascript, json, swift, date, nsdate

I am trying to convert a date in which the javascript code is generating the current date using the Date() function. But when I print it out, I am getting nil.

my code:

```
        let date2 = data?[0] as! String
        println(date2)

        var str = "2013-07-21T19:32:00Z"

        var dateFor: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFor.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

        var Date: NSDate? = dateFor.dateFromString(date2)

        println(Date)
```

date2 => is printing out 2015-05-15T21:58:00.066Z
Date => is printing nil
str is just for testing and works perfectly.

Anyone see any flaws in the code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue is that `str` and `date2` two are not the same date format. `str` format is `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"` while `date2` format is `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`. Besides that you should always set your dateFormatter's locale to `"en_US_POSIX"` when parsing fixed-format dates:

```
let date2 = "2015-05-15T21:58:00.066Z"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date2) {
    print(date)  // "2015-05-15 21:58:00 +0000"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ISO8601DateFormatter` per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) going forward

> In macOS 10.12 and later or iOS 10 and later, use the
> ISO8601DateFormatter class when working with ISO 8601 date
> representations.

```
import Foundation

let isoStr = "2020-02-18T11:40:01.000Z"

let isoDateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
isoDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
isoDateFormatter.formatOptions = [
    .withFullDate,
    .withFullTime,
    .withDashSeparatorInDate,
    .withFractionalSeconds]

if let isoDateFormatted = isoDateFormatter.date(from: isoStr) {
    print(isoDateFormatted)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4+**

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let str = "2013-07-21T19:32:00Z"

if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: str) {
    print(date)
}
```

**Output:** 2013-07-21 19:32:00 +0000